# How to transfer database from SQL Server to DB2?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, db2, migration

I have a database file on disk called `project.mdf`. I want to import this into IBM DB2. How do I import this database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migrating between platforms is not always an easy task. Besides the changes in schema and SQL code, the data itself may not be an exact fit between platforms. For example, a TIMESTAMP in SQL Server is not the same as a TIMESTAMP in Oracle.

Microsoft offers the [SQL Server Migration Assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ssma/), but that is for getting data into SQL Server, not for exporting to other platforms.

The only company I know that [offers tools and knowledge for migrating from SQL Server to DB2 is Ispirer](https://www.ispirer.com/products/sql-server-to-db2-migration). I've never used their tools however, but you may want to start with them.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do a DDL extraction (not sure how) and that you could then run against DB2.

The data you could export in CSV format and then use db2import to bring the data in. You would probably want to make note of the codepage the data is in, in case you need to do codepage conversion with the import operation.

Comment: And all that assumes you run a "stupid" database. The moment you have logic in there - triggers, stored procedures - the DDL Extraction turns into a "transpose different sql dialects" nightmare.

Comment: @TomTom - very true. My mindset was thinking mostly about the data and the tables it resides in.